# Does Bada support the use and creation of dynamic link libraries for applications?

Tags: shared-libraries, bada

As I know Samsung Bada is not operating system but, just wonder if I can develop DLL like shared library for Bada applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of SDK/IDE v.1.0.0 beta 1 RC8, you can also create bada dynamic libraries (dll)

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is this just for SDK and emulator only or target device also?

Comment: Anything that's possible on the emulator should be possible on the target device also.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot create shared libraries, but you don't really need to because bada does not features multi-tasking. But you can create static libraries.